# How to add blank space on an image to fit a given size when image is too small

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have images that have different size (lower than 200x200 px) I want them to be 200x200 px by adding blank space with a given color (white for example).
I tried to crop them using the crop lib: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html
I doesn't work.
Here is some code I'm using without success:

```
$config = Array(
 'image_library' => 'gd2',
 'source_image' => '/path/to/my/image.jpg',
 'new_image' => '/path/to/my/small/image.jpg',
 'thumb_marker' => '',
 'create_thumb' => TRUE,
 'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
 'width' => '200',
 'height' => '200'
);

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
{
 $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error',  $this->image_lib->display_errors());
 redirect('/mon_controller', 'location');
}

$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/my/small/image.jpg';
$config['x_axis'] = '200';
$config['y_axis'] = '200';

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->image_lib->crop())
{
 $this->session->set_flashdata('message_error',  $this->image_lib->display_errors());
 redirect('/my_controller', 'location');
}
```

**EDIT**: I think that lib fit my needs: http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/

Comment: Do you want to generate an image with the space filled with a colour or would a CSS solution be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need this .

```
http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/
```

Comment: Indeed. It totally did the job and it's freaking easy to use :) many thanks. This did the job:
`$this->image_moo->load('/path/to/my/image.jpg')->set_background_colour("#ffffff")->resize_crop(200,200)->save('/path/to/my/small/image.jpg', TRUE);`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not answering your question, but I suggest doing it with CSS, so you can keep the original images and be able to use them anywhere later (what if your design changes tomorrow? or want to use them in another page that doesn't need the same images' size requirements?).

Simply put the image into a div, and style it with `margin: auto;` (or `text-align: center`, can't say right now) to horizontally center it.
To vertically center it, you can use this jQuery function:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function(){
    return this.each(function(i){
    var ah = $(this).height();
    var ph = $(this).parent().height();
    var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
    $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
};
```

And then: `$('#image').vAlign()`.